# Comparing 2 dates in bash

Tags: bash, debian

So I am trying to compare 2 dates in bash , but my dates contains characters like Jan or Monday .
Can I compare them directly or do i need to format them like this "20201607"(and how do i do this plz) and them numerically compare them?
Thank you
For example:

```
today=$(date)
day='21 Jan 2021'

if [ $today < $day ]
   echo "$day"
```

basically my function will just return the dates who does not happened atm.

Comment: Is the input date complete free-form? Is it something you get from the user with no control over the date formatting?

Comment: What date format is `20201607` -- when I look at that I think "there is no 16th month"

Comment: Actually i get it from --calendar option on zenity . it is then send to a text file . i suppose it is a string at this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Zenity can help you: Tell zenity what output date format you want:

```sh
while ! date=$(zenity --calendar --date-format '%Y%m%d'); do
    # ...........................^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    echo "Don't cancel the zenity window, select a day"
done

# bash v4.2+ can to date formatting
today=$(printf '%(%Y%m%d)T' -1)

if [ "$date" -gt "$today" ]; then
    echo "you entered a future date"
fi
```

Comment: Thank you , to fix it , i transformed the date in a integer format with year month and day and then compare it numerically.

Answer (score 3):

Use the date to seconds since the epoch (1970-01-01 UTC) through specifying %s with date and so:

```
day='21 Jan 2021'
if [[ "$(date +%s)" -lt "$(date -d "$day" +%s)" ]];
then 
    echo "$day";
fi
```